# What would a 9th-century German count do if he wanted to spend some time with his wife?

Tags: early-medieval, nobility, entertainment

Are there any records of leisure activities by married noble couples in approximately 821? 
What sort of things can they both do? Did women go on hunts with men? Could there have been a theater, or a particularly sparkling mass in the local church? What sorts of entertainment or general bonding activities was there for a low-to-mid-tier noble that men and women could do together?

It is the Year of our LORD 821. Count Aldwin (31) of [Hattuaria](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Hettergouw.jpg) and Countess Sigihild (26)'s relationship has gone sour after her miscarriage and his alleged affair with the kitchen maid (which is totally fake news), so Aldwin wants so take her out on an activity they can enjoy together, hoping to regain the spark they had in the earlier years of their marriage.

Answer (score 10):

A count in the 9th century? Well, then we are speaking not just about a very rich person, we are speaking about a **head of his own state**. He is not subject to any other state authority except loose alliances. Possibly he respects the authority of the Pope and/or Charlemagne, but that's it. He also can be opposed to both.

He definitely would not go to theatre or a mass with his wife. Rather, he could organise a huge dinner in his own domain, maybe in his own castle. He can invite actors, best chefs, and other artisans.

Comment: I mean, technically the area in question is a Gau ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau_(territory) ), the count of which was appointed by the Frankish emperor. I would not consider them their own states, and the office only became hereditary during the 9th century when said empire was divided up. The independence question aside, I can't say I know the level of wealth such an individual would acquire (that's something for another question), but your suggestions sound reasonable.

Answer (score -6):

This probably more a philosophical question than a historical one

- or at least the answer is

> What would a 9th-century ...  wanted to spend some time with his wife?

Probably something similar to what someone in

- ancient Greece, Rome at the time of Caesar and today

would do.

Offspring don't inherent automatically lessons learned by previous generations. Such lessons must be taught.

So most of the problems that peaple have, have been problems (in most cases) that generations in the past have had.

The same is true for the methods to **resove** such problems, whereby the ratio of thoses that **don't work** to those that **do work** is probably also the same.

---

If a list it to be build on how general, common, problems were delt with in the past - one would start by determining how it is done today

- ignoring aspects that exist to day, that didn't exist then

  - usage of cars, mobile phones etc.

Inviting someone else for a walk or ride in the countryside to talk to each other could be # 1 of that list.

Ignoring **brilliant idea #539679** (that never worked in previous generations) while doing so is helpful.

But it seems that the resistance to do so,  is genetically inherited through out all generations, when such a lesson is taught by an elder to a younger person.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I really do not see that this is an answer to the OPs question (in as far as it is possible to answer it)

Comment: @bigbadmouse Nobody today can answer it. But a list of possibles can be made, if one assumes that History repeats itself is true.